# How to get a certain column from a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace the text and css of the 3rd column of a certain table row,
I have unique id from button on each row..

Iv'ed seen some doing this `$('#feedbacks tr:nth-child(3) td')`

here's a row from my table

```
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0">awdawd</td>
      <td>awdawd@dawd.com</td>
      <td>
         <span class="text-success">Opened</span>
      </td>
      <td>04:16PM Wednesday - 21st Aug 2019</td>
      <td class=" text-center">
         <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="view" class="btn btn-simple btn-info btn-icon view" id="77">
            <i class="material-icons">pageview</i>
         </button>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: First, an ID should not start with a number, second what text and css do you want to change, and to what?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, Thank you for your response. Yes I'm aware of the ID.. its just for testing purposes. and about the 3rd column here's an example of what i'm trying to do `$('#feedbacks tr:nth-child(3) td').text("opened/unread")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that on click each tr view button you want to change 3rd td span class and text. Then do as follows -

```
$(document).on('click', '.view', function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(3) span').text("Unread").removeClass("text-success").addClass("text-error");
});
```

Comment: This will select 3rd columns of all rows.. How could I make it select a certain row?

Comment: Basically I gave the part of jquery to change the span class and text. You have to this in your event handler. Anyway I updated above codes. Please check.

Comment: Its okay now.. the code you gave worked but when I put it in an if statement it seems not to..  so I made a variable`var viewButton = this;` and replaced the `this` with `viewButton` variable and it worked Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can change the text by using Jquery like below.

are you changing your table content on every row's button click? then

```
$('.view').on('click',function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').find('span').html('changed Text').css('color','#fdcc');
});
```

or like this

```
$("td:nth-child(3)").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.. I can feel that the first answer you gave is very near :D
Here's the code that triggers the button
`table.on('click', '.view', function() {..})`

Comment: yes you can use the code then, also you can use `$('.view').on('click',function(){}`

Comment: This will select/change all 3rd columns that has `.view` class in it..
it needs a Unique identifier like the id on the button, but I just don't know how..

Answer (score 0):

try this selector.
tr td:nth-child(3)

Better to have a unique ID for the table

## mytable tr td:nth-child(3)